# Retrieve related data with parse and ios sdk

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm just trying to retrieve related data into my app with Parse but I'm getting some problems.
I have 2 tables, Travel and City, Travel has a related field called origin-city. I'm using a pointer in Data Browser to relate both of them.

So in **queryForTable** method i'm using

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query includeKey:@"origin-city"];
    return query;
```

}

And I'm always getting the pointer Id but not the City name that's what I really need.
This is the proper method for doing this ? how could I retrieve the name of the city ?

**Edit**

When I print the origin city I'm getting **City:M0PwR0OiLj:(null)** where M0PwR0OiLj is the objectId for City, here I need the name

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a `PFQueryTableViewController`, as the method `queryForTable` belongs to that. The error stating that a query is already in progress is because the query is fired behind the scenes by the PFQTVC, so the answer asking to do a `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is not possible in your case.

With this special table view controller, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is also passed a `PFObject`, which is the object to matching the row.

To get the city name, which is from **related** object, you use this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
PFObject *city = object[@"origin-city"];
[cell.textLabel setText:city[@"name"]; // The name column from the City class
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you use the - (PFQuery *)queryForTable it will return the results it pulls to
cell for row at index path so you could try something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

 [cell.textLabel setText:[object objectForKey:@"origin-city"]];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: hi @zoruc I updated my answer with the value I'm getting for **[object objectForKey:@"origin-city"]];** thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1. `self.parseClassName` contains the className string "Travel"
2. from your Parse web dashboard, ensure the "origin-city" column in "Travel" class is really a pointer of type "City"
3. pointer refer to a City row that still exist

Remember that each empty field (from web dashboard you can see the fields/columns with the "undefined" placeholder into them) is not returned in the result query. So it means that if you have an empty (so, undefined) column "name" in the "City" className, you won't be able to read it. Anyway the selection should be like this:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * travels, NSError *error) {

    if (error) 
        return;

    for (PFObject *travelX in travels) {

        PFObject *city = travelX[@"origin-city"]; // or [travelX objectForKey:@"origin-city"] if you prefer

        if (city){

            NSString* objectId = city.objectId;
            NSDate* createdAt = city.createdAt;
            NSString* cityName = city[@"name"];
            NSLog("The city name is %@", ( cityName ? cityName : @"<NOT DEFINED>" ) );

        }else
            NSLog(@"%@",@"There is no city for this travel");    

    }
}];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Luca laco thanks for your help, I checked above 3 steps and everything is fine, so I put your code after **[query includeKey:@"origin-city"];** line and now I'm getting **This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.**

Comment: Is it possible that query is already in progress? try to call [query cancel] before [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ....]. Do you have also the latest SDK version? Check  this post , could be helpful https://parse.com/questions/this-object-has-an-outstanding-network-connection-you-have-to-wait-until-its-done