# Messaging App Swift - showing all conversations

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, chat, message

I am making an app which includes user to user private messaging. My only problem is getting all the conversations or recent messages of the current user, I don't know how to pull this information out of a database using PARSE.

My database has two tables, a user one and a messages one. There is one entry for every message sent with a senderId and a recipientId.

I have no clue how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using CoreData? You don't know how to query database? You don't know how to write this specific query? What is your question exactly?

Comment: @kostek sorry, I'm using parse. I'm allowing users to send messages to each other, but I want to display the current users conversations/recent messages he has with other users on a table. that's what I'm asking

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you found sth in parse documentation or guide?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those links will be helpful:

https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery

[Retrieve related data with parse and ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402612/retrieve-related-data-with-parse-and-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let sentMessagesQuery = PFUser.query()!
sentMessagesQuery.whereKey("senderId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

let receivedMessagesQuery = PFUser.query()!
receivedMessagesQuery.whereKey("recipientId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([sentMessagesQuery, receivedMessagesQuery])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //Do stuff with the result
})
```

Comment: but this can't be used to return all the users the current user is messaging.